# symbol errno, version GLIBC_2.0 not defined, in opensuse Linux 11.4

Tags: linux, glibc, opensuse

I have a third-party 32-bit executable that I need to run on OpenSuSE Linux 11.4.
When i run it, I get this error:

filename: relocation error: filename: symbol errno, version GLIBC_2.0 not defined in file libc.so.6 with link time reference.

in /lib directory, libc.so.6 as a symbolic link, points to libc-2.11.3.so. When I do an objdump of this and grep for errno, i get this:

```
00000008 g D  .tbss 00000004 GLIBC_PRIVATE  errno
000171c0 g DF .text 0000001d GLIBC_2.0      __errno_location
000f96e0 g DF .text 0000007d GLIBC_2.0      clnt_sperrno
000f98a0 g DF .text 0000003d GLIBC_2.0      clnt_perrno
00000034 g D  .tbss 00000004 GLIBC_PRIVATE  h_errno
000ec860 g DF .text 0000001d GLIBC_2.0      __h_errno_location
```

I don't have the source code of the executable. Is there a way I can add a patch myself to the source of glibc and  fix this problem locally on my machine alone?

If that is possible, then, what is the patch?

The executable is third-party's version of lmgrd, the utility that starts their license server.

Executable's ldd output looks like this:

```
linux-gate.so.1 =>  (0xffffe000)
libpthread.so.0 => /lib/libpthread.so.0 (0xf76a5000)
libc.so.6 => /lib/libc.so.6 (0xf753c000)
/lib/ld-linux.so.2 (0xf76f6000)
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: what does `ldd <binary>` output?

Comment: Thanks for the response, Subhasis. I've added the ldd output.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> `relocation error: filename: symbol errno, version GLIBC_2.0 not defined in file libc.so.6 with link time reference.`
>
> The executable is third-party's version of lmgrd, the utility that starts their license server.

That executable must have been linked on an ancient machine. Here is a good [explanation](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=168540) of the problem.

> Is there a way I can add a patch myself to the source of glibc and fix this problem locally on my machine alone?

Yes, but you really shouldn't do that (it's (a) complicated, and (b) you can easily render your system unbootable if you screw up your glibc).

Contact the 3rd party vendor and tell them that you can't use their product due to broken `lmgrd`. Ask for your money back. You may be surprised how motivated they may become trying to solve this problem.

Comment: Thanks very much, Employed Russian. You are right about everything u wrote and the last piece of ur advice is something that I have to show to my bosses.. :-)